# Getting the minimum of the rows in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, min

I am working with a dataframe that has 65 variables in it. The first variable catalogs a person, and the next 64 variables indicate the geographic distance that person is from each of 64 locations. Using R, I would like to create a new variable that catalogs the shortest distance for each person to one of those 64 locations.

For example: if person X is 35, 50, 79, 100, 450...miles away from the locations, I would like the new variable to automatically assign them a 35, because this is the shortest distance. 
Any help with this would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: df$newvariable=apply(df[,2:65],1,min)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(let=letters[1:25], d1=sample(1:25,25), d2=sample(1:25,25), d3=sample(1:25,25))

df$shortest <- apply(df[,2:4],1,min)
```

The second line applies the function min to each row and assigns it to the new column in my data.frame df.  See `?apply` for more explanation of what the second line is doing.  Careful to skip the first column, or any columns that aren't distances:

`apply(df,1,min)` gives completely difference answers since its finding the "min" of strings.

```
> min(2:10)
[1] 2
> min(as.character(2:10))
[1] "10"
```

Answer (score 12):

Or, using the example of Justin:

```
df$shortest <- do.call(pmin,df[-1])
```

see also `?pmin` and `?do.call`, and note that you can drop the first variable in your data frame by using the list indices (so not using any comma at all, see also `?Extract` )

Answer (score 4):

I'd approach this with apply but transform or other approach could work.

```
#fake data set
ID=LETTERS[1:5], distance=matrixsample(
DF <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:100, rep=T, 100), 5, 20))
DF <- data.frame(ID=LETTERS[1:5], DF)

#solution
DF$newvar <- apply(DF[,-1], 1, min)
```